# How to add appsettings.json to a Maui project that will work cross-platform?

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor

I added an appsetting.json file to the project's Resources/Raw folder

Then added the following to my mauiprogram.cs

```
var a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

using var stream = a.GetManifestResourceStream("myassembly.appsettings.json");

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonStream(stream).Build();

builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);
```

Compiles fine after adding the appropriate using but the stream is always null.

How can I add cross-platform appsettings?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [documentation](https://montemagno.com/dotnet-maui-appsettings-json-configuration/) and this [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/953861/maui-appsettingsjson-not-copying-to-device.html). Remember to set the properties Build Action of appsettings.jsonto "Embedded Resource"

Comment: Please do not add greetings and salutations to your posts. Stack Overflow strives to be a high-quality knowledge base and is not Microsoft's help desk. Please also read [this question addressed to Microsoft employees](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419331/5211833) and **finally pass the message along** in the company that even you lofty Microsoft employees should still adhere to Stack Overflow's rules.

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple, you can use the 'Raw' folder for appsettings management.
You can read the file as stream and pass it to the Configuration builder.